# 'ionic cordova run android' build failed - in ionic 3

Tags: cordova, ionic3

I am working In **Ionic 3** project. When I run the command `ionic cordova run android` it shows following error and builds failed.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>
> Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>
> > File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.    Searched Location:
> >     D:\IONIC\azmaeen\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\debug\google-services.json
> >     D:\IONIC\azmaeen\platforms\android\app\src\debug\nullnull\google-services.json
> >     D:\IONIC\azmaeen\platforms\android\app\src\nullnull\google-services.json
> >     D:\IONIC\azmaeen\platforms\android\app\src\debug\google-services.json 
> >     D:\IONIC\azmaeen\platforms\android\app\src\nullnullDebug\google-services.json
> >     D:\IONIC\azmaeen\platforms\android\app\google-services.json
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 11s (node:14068) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning:
>   Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise
>   rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process
>   with a non-zero exit code.
>
> [OK] Your app has been deployed.
>        Did you know you can live-reload changes from your app with --livereload?

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to download the google-services.json file. (Whenever you used google related functionalities you should create the google service json)

1. First, you have to create a google-service json file from your Google account.
2. Then download that file and paste in platforms\android\app\src folder.

It Will solves your issue

Comment: I've created an account on google and downloaded google-services.json and paste it "`platforms\android\app\src`". **Still not working**